# Fonts & Character Sets ⇒ How to create upright Greek lowercase letters

Tags: symbols

I am using the template of the Proceedings of the Royal Society A. In this template, I cannot produce upright Greek lowercase letters. For example, I use the command "\deltaup" to produce an upright delta, but the result is still the italic delta rather than the upright one. For the uppercase Greek characters, I used the command "\let\Deltaup\Delta" before \begin{document}, and it worked, however, it did not work for the lowercase delta. Could you please let me know how I can resolve this problem? (I copied the packages used in my document down below).
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[openacc]{rsproca_new}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\newcommand{\upDeltaup}{\upDelta}
\newcommand{\updeltaup}{\updelta}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,margin=20pt]{caption}
\usepackage[title,header]{appendix}

\usepackage{relsize} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{physics}
\newcommand\bmmax{0} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%%%%%% Defining Enunciations  %%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{condition}{\bf Condition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{\bf Corollary}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titlehead{Research}

\let\Deltaup\Delta
\let\deltaup\delta
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Without a minute malworking example it would be hard to test any answer, but why don't you just use `\updelta` instead? (also read `texdoc upgreek`) (by the way there's some confusion here as `\let\deltaup\delta` defines `\deltaup` to output whatever `\delta` normally output i.e. an italic δ, so of course you should expect an italic δ.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this template, I cannot produce upright Greek lowercase letters.

That's not right. As @user202729 has already pointed out in a comment, you should just use `\upalpha`, `\upbeta`, ... , `\upomega`. FWIW, with a definition such as `\let\deltaup\delta`, `\deltaup` is *guaranteed* to produce the same, viz. slanted, output as `\delta`.

You should also think about removing quite a bit of cruft and code debris from your preamble. By doing so, it'll become much easier to spot inconsistencies and misunderstandings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[openacc,a4paper]{rsproca_new} % see https://royalsocietypublishing.org/rspa/for-authors

\jname{rspa} % or whatever is appropriate
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage{dblfloatfix} % why?
%%\usepackage{fixltx2e} % not needed

\usepackage{float}   % you sure?
\usepackage{wrapfig} % ditto
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % loaded automatically by 'rotating'
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,
            margin=20pt]{caption}
\usepackage[title,header]{appendix}

%\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek} % for '\upalpha', '\upbeta', etc

\usepackage{relsize} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%%%%%\usepackage{latexsym} % why??
\usepackage{physics}
%\newcommand\bmmax{0} 

\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{condition}{\bf Condition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{\bf Corollary}[section]

\titlehead{Research}

%%\let\Deltaup\Delta % <-- huh?
%%\let\deltaup\delta % <-- huh?

\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma \chi\psi\omega$ 
$\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma \upchi\uppsi\upomega$
\end{document}
```